# how disable all btn if the one of button is selected javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hi i have a problem that i'd like to do all btns are disabled when a user chooses one of the buttons and all of them disabled this is my goal well i started by doing a loop iterative to get all of buttons and took the button that was pressed by the user i used the repeat and then checked if the button pressed does something anyway here is my code

```js
//get btn that is pressed by user
idbtn = data.path[1].children[7].children[0].id;
var btn = document.getElementById(idbtn) // info btn

//get all btns. also include btn is pressed by user
for (j = 0; j + 1 <= data.path[2].children.length; j++) {
  let btnN = "epBtn" + j
  var otherBtn = document.getElementById(btnN); // info btns
  if (otherBtn.id[btn.id]) {
    console.log("test");
  }
```

Comment: Anything particularly wrong with using `<input type="radio">`?

Comment: @Tibrogargan radio wdym? i use btn not radio and everything is working fine with html

Comment: Shouldn't `otherBtn.id[btn.id]` be `otherBtn.id === btn.id` or something like that?

Comment: @TechySharnav i tried it and it works but it prints word test for me with all the buttons

Comment: It's not totally clear as to what is the actual objective is. Is it click a button and the other buttons are disabled? Or is it click a button and disable all buttons including the button that the user clicked?

Comment: @zer00ne the idea is if i have buttons located on the td table and i'd like to check all the buttons on the column, if the user presses the first button it locks other buttons If he chooses second button is pressed for example the first and third buttons will be locked and samething

Comment: You really need to include an [mcve], it's kind of unclear what you want right now.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init)

function init() {
    document.getElementById("check").addEventListener("click",
    event => {
        for (radio of document.getElementsByName("the-radio")) {
            if (radio.checked) {
                console.log(radio.value); return
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
<button type="button">
  <label for="r1">One</label>
  <input style="visibility:hidden" name="the-radio" type="radio" value="one" id="r1" checked="true">
</button>
<button type="button">
  <label for="r2">Two</label>
  <input style="visibility:hidden" name="the-radio" type="radio" value="two" id="r2">
</button>
<button type="button">
  <label for="r3">Red</label>
  <input style="visibility:hidden" name="the-radio" type="radio" value="red" id="r3">
</button>
<button type="button">
  <label for="r4">Blue</label>
  <input style="visibility:hidden" name="the-radio" type="radio" value="blue" id="r4">
</button>
<button type="button">
  <label for="r5">Arbitrary Value</label>
  <input style="visibility:hidden" name="the-radio" type="radio" value="whatever" id="r5">
</button>
</fieldset><br />
<button type="button" id="check">Show Value</button>
```

This might also be what you wanted, hard to tell sorry

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init)

function init() {
    document.addEventListener("click", event => {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('grid')) {
            clas = event.target.classList.contains('vert')? 'vert':'hor'
            for (button of document.getElementsByClassName(clas)) button.disabled = true
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td></td><td><button class="grid vert" value="A">A</button></td><td><button class="grid vert" value="B">B</button></td><td><button class="grid vert" value="C">C</button></td><tr>
<tr><td><button class="grid hor" value="1">1</button></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="grid hor" value="2">2</button></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="grid hor" value="3">3</button></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```